# How are the values for velocity and mass found?

Tags: physics

I'm confused as to how and where the solutions have derived the mass and velocity of A and B in this question. If someone could help me understand, that would be great.
[image: Problem 16.46]

Comment: This isn't [tag:arithmetic], and it's really not [tag:arithmetic-dynamics]. That being said, I have no idea where 9600, 5400, 15000, 2 and 1 come from.

Comment: I suspect that there's an error. The ratio of the masses in the problem statement is $400$, while in the equation, the masses are set at $9600$ and $5400$, which have a ratio of less than two. In addition, the resulting speed is much smaller than the velocities in the problem statement - again suspicious. So if I were you, I would just disregard the shown problem solution as erronous.

Comment: @Arthur: I've removed the inappropriate tags and added the physics tag.

Comment: relativity perhaps ?